# child component writes data in console multiple times in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm passing data to child component input property from parent component.  I'm showing that data in html table in child component.  Also I've added an extra button called "Add" in the loop with [disabled] property.  And I'm trying to enable/disable the button by calling "enableButton(item)" method.  I'm just trying to show the data in the console.  So, I just added console.log(item) inside enableButton() method.

my question is why it is repeating the items in the console.  I'm expecting only 4 items in the console window?

Here is the sample app that I've created in stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tt5fi7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

[image]

In my actual project, I'm doing the same thing.  The only difference is, I'm using p-table and p-column. I've noticed that data is being repeated for 1000 of times in the console window. not sure why?

Can someone explain why and provide best solution to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `disabled` attribute's value is determined by the `enableButton` function.

This function is therefore called on every Angular tick and for each input.

**That's why you don't bind to functions in the template.**

Comment: Since I have only 4 items it will loop 4 times and supposed to call the function 4 times right? Didn’t get your answer.  Can you explain me more plz?    What’s the best solution to enable/disable the button?  Can you suggest me a best solution plz?

Comment: Your functions is called 4 times for each Angular cycle (once for each input). It looks like an Angular app needs 2 cycles to start. When in dev mode, Angular runs each cycles twice to warn you about unwanted behaviors. So it's a total of 4 cycles to start in dev mode, therefore 4x4 console logs.

Comment: Okay, got it. What's the best solution to achieve this?

Comment: You have to pre-compute the values when the app starts and store them into your items, you then only have to do `[disabled]="item.disabled"`

Comment: The same thing I did, it's working for me.  Thanks for your information and time. :)